# EhCache Empty Cache

Tags: ehcache

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) or whether I have just not implemented it properly but after having saved something to the cache, when I go to retrieve it I have an empty cache!

Basically I am trying to use ehcache to replace the use of @Singleton. I need a single place in the application where I can store in memory data that can be accessed and shared from multiple places in the application.

My current code is as follows:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class DevicePoll {

...

@Schedule(minute = "*/2", hour = "*")
    protected void getStatus() {
        // Get all the sites
        List<Site> sites = siteDAO.findAllSites();

        // Setup the cache manager
        CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
        Cache cache = manager.getCache("DEVICE_STATUS_CACHE");

        // For testing lets get an item that we know was placed
        Element e = cache.get("201");

        for (Site site : sites) {
            // Obtain the devices
            List<Device> devices = deviceUtil.getDeviceTree(site);

            // Create a new element and place it in the cache
            Element element = new Element(site.getId(), devices);
            cache.put(element);

        }
        // Shutdown the cache manager
        manager.shutdown();
    }

...
}
```

My ehcache.xml is:

```
<defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30" maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
<persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</defaultCache>

<cache name="DEVICE_STATUS_CACHE" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" eternal="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO"/>
```

Comment: Is this Spring framework based app?

Comment: No, I'm not using Spring.

Answer (score 1):

`CacheManager` are highlanders, you must have only one. As you create and destroy it in your method, nothing is saved, you need something more like that:

```
public class DevicePoll {

    // usually cache and cache manager are injected
    private Cache cache;

    public DevicePoll() {
        final CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
        this.cache = manager.getCache("DEVICE_STATUS_CACHE");
    }

    @Schedule(minute = "*/2", hour = "*")
    protected void getStatus() {
        // Get all the sites
        List<Site> sites = siteDAO.findAllSites();

        // For testing lets get an item that we know was placed
        Element e = cache.get("201");

        for (Site site : sites) {
            // Obtain the devices
            List<Device> devices = deviceUtil.getDeviceTree(site);

            // Create a new element and place it in the cache
            Element element = new Element(site.getId(), devices);
            cache.put(element);

        }
    }

    // ...
}
```